# Convert Update CRUD Form Date in Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb, date, crud, utc

When the date of 3/2/2021 is selected on my create CRUD form in Angular, it is passed to mongodb as 2021-03-02T00:00:00.000+00:00, then displayed on my update CRUD form as 2021-03-02T00:00:00.000Z.  How can I convert that to 'M/d/yyyy'?

(On my my details table I can do this using the date pipe {{risk.submission_date | date: 'M/d/yyyy'}}, but cannot on the update form because I am using <form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()"> to edit each specific Id.)

```js
 this.crudService.GetRisk(this.getId).subscribe(res => {
      this.updateForm.setValue({ 
        submission_date: res['submission_date'],
        ...
        
this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      submission_date: ['', Validators.required],
      ...
```

```html
<div class="card-body widget-body">
  <form [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input-12">Submission Date</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm checking-field" formControlName="submission_date" required disabled>
      <span class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="updateForm.get('submission_date').touched && updateForm.get('submission_date').hasError('required')">Date is required</span>                              
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the data from the service, you can format the date string before setting it in the form. You can use a library like [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for that.

```
import moment from 'moment';
...
this.crudService.GetRisk(this.getId).subscribe(res => {
      this.updateForm.setValue({ 
        submission_date: moment(res['submission_date']).format('YYYY/MM/DD'),
        ...
```

```
moment('2021-03-02T00:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY/MM/DD'); // => 03/02/2021
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I just had to add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true to the config.json file.